# Consultas Banco de dados MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Atualmente tenho estudando SQL Server e My SQL na faculdade, porém tendo muita dificuldade em efetuar consultas no banco de dados. O banco tem 3 tebelas (`aluno`, `discuplina` e `matricula`)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

1. Mostrar o valor total das mensalidades pagas por alunos por curso (só para alunos que tenham se matriculado em alguma disciplina).
2. Mostre quantas aprovações cada curso tem (por nota e falta).
3. Mostre quantos alunos já fora reprovados por falta, mas passariam por nota.

```
SELECT aluno.nome 
FROM aluno, matricula 
WHERE aluno.ra = matricula.ra
  AND faltas > faltas - (faltas * 0.9)
  AND (nota1 + nota2) / 2 > 7; (15)
```

Repita a consulta anterior, mostrando os dados separados por curso.

4. Mostre o número de matrículas por ano e a média geral das médias obtidas nessas matrículas por ano.

Comment: não sei se entendi bem mas você quer resposta para os 4 itens? no caso, quatro consultas inteiras?

Comment: Queria entender como fazer esse tipo de consulta que são mais especificas.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp essa página vai te ajudar.. tem funções de soma, média e contador, você vai precisar delas ;)

Answer (score 1):

Não conhecendo exatamente os campos de cada tabela eu tenho dificuldade de lhe ajudar mais.
Contudo, deixo abaixo uma explicação das funções que em minha visão podem te ajudar a solucionar as questões.

### Questão 1

*Mostrar o valor total das mensalidades pagas por alunos por curso (só para alunos que tenham se matriculado em alguma disciplina).*

#### Resposta

- Nesta questão você deverá juntar as tabelas para que as informações se disponham em uma único "tabelão". Ou seja, as informações do aluno, quais disciplinas ele esta vinculado e as informações de matricula ficaram todas na mesma linha.
  Para isso use o INNER JOIN, usando campo que permitam "conectar" uma tabela na outra. Por exemplo `id_matricula` na tabela aluno com `id_matricula` na tabela disciplina.
- Assumindo que o valor das mensalidades estão na tabela disciplina, você pode usar a função SUM para somar os valores do campo `valor_mensalidade`
- Para agrupar os dados dos cursos e alunos basta usar o GROUP BY

O código para juntar as tabelas ficaria assim

```
SELECT aluno.nome, disciplina.curso, sum(matricula.valor_mensalidade) FROM aluno
INNER JOIN matricula ON aluno.id_matricula = matricula.id_matricula
INNER JOIN disciplina ON disciplina.id_matricula = aluno.id_matricula
GROUP BY aluno.nome, disciplina.curso
```

Após juntas

### Questão 02

*Mostre quantas aprovações cada curso tem (por nota e falta).*

#### Resposta

- Assumindo que na tabela `aluno` se situam as notas e e faltas, você precisa vincular a tabela alunos a tabela disciplina por algo igual ao feito na questão 01.
- Após verificar adicionar os critérios, usando a clausula `WHERE` para que somente os alunos que foram aprovados sejam retornados, pelo exemplo que você mesmo citou o critério para aprovação por falta é `faltas > faltas - (faltas * 0.9)` e a aprovação por nota tem o critério `(nota1 + nota2) / 2 > 7`
  PS: Eu não entendi a expressão (nota1 + nota2) / 2 > 7;(15)
- Você também precisará contar a quantidade de registros que o `SELECT` irá retornar, pode usar a função `COUNT`.
- Será necessário também usar o `GROUP BY` para agrupar os dados por curso

o código ficaria assim

```
SELECT disciplina.curso, count(*) FROM alunos
INNER JOIN disciplina ON alunos.id_matricula = disciplina.id_matricula
WHERE disciplina.faltas > .disciplinafaltas - (disciplina.faltas * 0.9)
GROUP BY disciplina.curso
```

PS2: A meu ver falta uma tabela que relacione o aluno a varias disciplinas.

### Questão 03

*Mostre quantos alunos já fora reprovados por falta, mas passariam por nota.*

Se até aqui estiver fazendo sentido volto e preencho.

### Questão 04

*Mostre o número de matrículas por ano e a média geral das médias obtidas nessas matrículas por ano.*

Se até aqui estiver fazendo sentido volto e preencho.